# compassion on nuxmv/nusmv - CTL and next

Tags: nusmv, nuxmv

1. Is there any way to use compassion for CTL?
2. Is an option to write an expression with next(state) on compassion expression?
   Thanks

Comment: I think this two question is not related together

Comment: NuSMV 2.6 Manual quote: *"In the current version of NUSMV, compassion constraints are supported only for BDD-based LTL model checking. We plan to add support for compassion constraints also for CTL specifications and in Bounded Model Checking in the next releases of NUSMV"*